# Swipe away my application from the recents activity kills my service

Tags: android, service, background-process

I created a service to handle my AsyncTasks like uploading a file on a server or downloading one. When I swipe away my app from the recent activity menu, my service is killed. Is it normal behaviour ? If so, one solution would be to set it as a foreground service with `startForeground(int, Notification)` but I must display a notification and I don't want it as I'm already displaying one for each AsyncTask running.

How does the "play store" app download applications and keep the downloads alive even if I swipe away the "play store" from the recent activity menu ?

Comment: I bet that play store do it with `startForeground`. I think that you should do it with it too. Because that's a normal behaviour.

Comment: So how can they display one notification per download ?

Comment: use the different ids per notification?

Comment: If you mean change the id in startForeground(ID,Notification) it won't work as the stopForeground(removeNotification) does not take an id as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, but you can make a normal notification when 1 download finish and then call `stopForeground` and call `startForeground` again this way you will keep the normal notification when the new download is in progress. This way you can change its id for the normal notifications

Answer (score 2):

> Is it normal behaviour ?

Yes. Android, at the user's request, terminated your background process.

> If so, one solution would be to set it as a foreground service with startForeground(int, Notification) but I must display a notification and I don't want it as I'm already displaying one for each AsyncTask running.

Please do not show a separate `Notification` "for each AsyncTask running". At most, show one `Notification`. Few, if any, apps are important enough to warrant separate `Notifications`.

Comment: I think it is fair to display one notification per upload. Google does the same thing with the play store

Comment: @Quanturium and that is very annoying. Please don't spam our notifications.